# Google Api not working on appended input

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

Background:

I am trying to add the google address search to an online storefront. I do not have access to the actual html of the site but I am allowed to input code into the header, footer, and include any css or js page I would like. I had everything working in the beginning. I had the input in the header and was able to search for an address.

[image]

Which created:

[image]

So after I got my code working it was time to move the input down below with the other address inputs. I wanted to use javascript to append this input in a div based on he parent ID. So I did this with this code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.createElement('div');
    input.setAttribute("id", "locationField");
    input.innerHTML = '<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onfocus="geolocate()" type="text" autocomplete="off">';

    var form = document.getElementById('NameAdd');
    form.insertBefore(input, form.firstChild);
};
```

Which produced this:

[image]

Now that I am including the input this way it is not showing google results. When inspecting the elements of the page everything looks fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you creating the `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` object?

Comment: In a javascript function called initAutoComplete() @geocodezip

Comment: @geocodezip it is the same function used in Google's example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: Please add it to your question to make a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` constructor takes a `<input>` element, not a `<div>`.

This works for me:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var inputDiv = document.createElement('div');
  inputDiv.setAttribute("id", "locationField");

  // create input element dynamically so don't need to wait for it to render
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute("id", "autocomplete");
  input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter your address");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
  inputDiv.appendChild(input);

  var form = document.getElementById('NameAdd');
  form.insertBefore(input, form.firstChild);
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<form id="NameAdd">
  <br />
  <input id="Name" value="name" />
  <input id="Address" value="address" />
</form>
```

Comment: I just tried this and I was able to get search results but now my inputs are no longer populating. I have attached the code. @geocodezip

Comment: That wasn't part of the original question.

Comment: I have marked your answer as a solution because it did work. I figured out what was happening. After appending the input to the page I had to recall one of my functions

Comment: I rolled back the question